# App session cookie not being created in Rails, sporadically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, memcached

This is an issue sporadically for very few users, however we haven't been able to replicate it. However I have now got a Chrome instance (Mac) which is reproducing the error (for some unknown reason), and I hope to not restart it until I have this nailed!

Rails application, using memcached for session store. While the bug manifests in the `_app_session_id` cookie not being created, our javascript-generated cookie test and app-generated language cookies are being created successfully. This means that  `InvalidAuthenticityToken` errors are thrown for every form that is submitted by those afflicted - people can't log into the app.

The error occurs across all browsers - had reports for IE7 and Firefox (which most users use). Switching to another browser often fixes the issue (though not always), and standard cache-cookie-clear tactics do not.

So now that I have got Chrome open which is having the same issue - in development, staging and live environments (meaning http and https). All other browsers are fine.

I've restarted the servers and restarted memcached. I don't really want to restart Chrome - in the risk that the issue *does* go away with that (having said that, it hasn't worked for users).

I've been tcpdumping the requests - and although I'll keep digging, I'd love it if anyone had any suggestions, places to start looking, anything. This is really painful ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can do the following to isolate the problem:

- take memcached off the equation
- create another rails app with same gem versions  and chech if the problem persists
- add memcached to the rails app and see if the problem persist